# date field projection in a chosen format in mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am not sure whether this can be done but I am putting out here to see anyone has any thoughts on it.

in my mongodb query for example if I do

```
 db.collection.find({_id:1}, {_id:0, myDt:1})
```

I get something like this

```
"myDt" : ISODate("1976-06-27T00:00:00.000Z")
```

my questions is is there anything I can do in projection to get date as string in this 'yyyy-mm-dd' format instead of all that ISODate(string)?

```
 db.collection.find({_id:1}, {_id:0, myDt:{do some magic work to get the yyyy-mm-dd back}})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It best to format your date using client-side processing**.

But of course you can do this by [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)ing your documents using the aggregation framework. In the `$project` stage you need to use the [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/), [`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) and [`$dayOfMonth`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/) operators which respectively return the year, month and day of a date as number. Of course to concatenate the value you first need to convert those number to string using the [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) and use the [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { 
            "_id": 0, 
            "date": { 
                "$concat": [
                    { "$toLower": { "$year": "$myDt" } }, 
                    "-", 
                    { "$toLower": { "$month": "$myDt" } }, 
                    "-", 
                    { "$toLower": { "$dayOfMonth": "$myDt" } } 
                 ]
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```

But you can always return the string date using the `$toLower` operator on your date:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { "$project": { "date": { "$toLower": "$myDt" } } } ] )
```

Comment: user3100115, I agree with you that formatting date at client side is the best option in this scenario. This is what we are doing now but thought of asking it here anyway. I appreciate your help for showing the aggregate query here.

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for the solution in 2021, you can use $dateToString in $project as bellow:

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project: {
          yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
          time: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S:%L", date: "$date" } }
       }
     }
   ]
)
```